# Deleting the checked items in listcontrol with extended style LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES

Tags: mfc, listcontrol

I am new to MFC. I have a listcontrol with `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`. I want to add delete functionality for the checked items in the listcontrol.

So far I have written a handler code to get notification from the `CListCtrl`:

```
void CAppDlg::OnListItemchanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    if (pLV->uNewState) // item checked
    {
        //delete functionality 
    }

    //by default allow change
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me. I have searched for examples over the net but I can't find any.

Comment: `OnListItemchanged` is called each time you check/uncheck or select/unselect an listview item, so this is not the place to do the deletion. You should have a "Delete" button and when the user clicks on that button, then you should scan your list control and delete all checked items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way of determining if the item check state has changed:

```
void CAttrSelectorDlg::OnLvnItemchangedAttrList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{   
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    int nItem = pNMLV->iItem;

    // get old check box state
    BOOL bPrevState = ( BOOL ) ( ( ( pNMLV->uOldState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK ) >> 12 ) - 1 );
    if ( bPrevState < 0 )   // On startup there's no previous state
        bPrevState = FALSE;  // assing as false (unchecked)

    // get new check box state
    BOOL bNewState = ( BOOL ) ( ( ( pNMLV->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK ) >> 12 ) - 1 );
    if ( bNewState < 0 )   // non-check box notification
        bNewState = FALSE;

    if (bPrevState != bNewState)
    {
        // state changed. DO STUFF
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

For your task I'd suggest using **Delete** button to delete selected (checked) items:

```
for (int i=0; i<m_AttrList.GetItemCount(); i++)
{
    BOOL bCheck = m_AttrList.GetCheck(i);
    if (bCheck)
    {
        // item is checked
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Komiagin. Can you please explain me the line ( ( ( pNMLV->uOldState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK ) >> 12 ) - 1 ).

Comment: Describe exactly what does not work? FYI: This is working code snippet from production code.

Comment: Regarding shift operator. The state field is a bit mask that contains 12 bits.